# In Python, using the sorted() method, is it possible to sort a list of dictionaries by a priority field?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of dictionaries and I sort them by multiple keys in a given order (1st 'Name', 2nd 'Start' and 3rd 'End'):

```
sorted_list = sorted(list, key=lambda dict: (dict['Name'], dict['Start'], -dict['End']))
```

I want the last sorting is done by a priority field:
the `dict['Status']` is a string name like "gene", "mRNA", "exon" and "CDS". The name "gene" must be higher than the others and "CDS" lower than the others.

Thanks for your answer,

Comment: So show us what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2):

First advice: **don't** use builtin-names as variable-names. You will be confused like hell when you try to use them later. E.g.

```
 dict = [1, 2, 3]
 d = dict(a="b")
```

will fail miserably. So - never call variables list, dict, file, str, int and all the others.

Your actual problem is solved by a simple lookup-table:

```
priorities = dict(gene=0, CDS=1000)
sorted_list = sorted(list, 
        key=lambda d: (d['Name'], d['Start'], -d['End'], 
        priorities.get(d['Status'], 1)))
```

Comment: Typo: Should be `priorities.get(d['Status'], 1)))` . I guess 1 would work as a default here, OTOH, I'd be tempted to _not_ supply a default, so if an invalid priority name turns up we get an explicit key error. And of course we can catch the KeyError exception and print the whole dict, if desired.